# Using std::deque::iterator (in C++ STL) for searching and deleting certain elements

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, deque

I have encountered a problem invoking the following code:

```
#include<deque>
using namespace std;

deque<int> deq = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

for(auto it = deq.begin(); it != deq.end(); it++){
    if(*it%2 == 0)
        deq.erase(it);
}
```

which resulted in a segmentation fault. After looking into the problem I found that the problem resides in the way the STL manages iterators for deques: if the element being erased is closer to the end of the deque, the iterator used to point to the erased element will now point to the NEXT element, but not the previous element as `vector::iterator` does. I understand that modifying the loop condition from `it != deq.end()` to `it < deq.end()` could possibly solve the problem, but I just wonder if there is a way to traverse & erase certain element in a deque in the "standard form" so that the code can be compatible to other container types as well.

Comment: Use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: You can do the operations inside the function (or function object) assigned to std::remove_if, then you can still use std::remove_if(as @Fraser suggested). I will suggest to use generic algorithms instead of plain loop, because the loop is not clear enough with your intention. Also, I think modifying and traversing the container at the same time is dangerous.

Comment: @chris Can you provide an example of remove_if for deque?  I've found that the final deque::erase(remove_if(...)) does not erase the correct items.  (In fact, the remove_if leaves the order of the deque unchanged, but places blanks in there.)  g++8/C++17.

Comment: @Daniel, There's a decent chance you hit the common mistake with `erase` and forgot to pass a second argument, meaning it erases one element. It [works here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bdYev3Eef). These seven years later, though, you can finally [do a bit better with C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vrTTb63d7) via `std::erase_if`. If `remove_if` is leaving "blanks" in, that sounds like a bug of some kind, either in implementation or in use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase

> All iterators and references are invalidated [...]
>
> **Return value : iterator following the last removed element.**

This is a common pattern when removing elements from an STL container inside a loop:

```
for (auto i = c.begin(); i != c.end() ; /*NOTE: no incrementation of the iterator here*/) {
  if (condition)
    i = c.erase(i); // erase returns the next iterator
  else
    ++i; // otherwise increment it by yourself
}
```

Or as [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) mentioned you could just use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Answer (score 13):

To use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), you'd do something like:

```
deq.erase(std::remove_if(deq.begin(),
                         deq.end(),
                         [](int i) { return i%2 == 0; }),
          deq.end());
```

Be sure to `#include <algorithm>` to make `std::remove_if` available.

Comment: Thanks this is also very useful information! But I have some additional operations associated with the elements to be removed so @syam 's solution suits me better. Thanks any way!