# std::deque memory corruption when using iterator to erase elements

Tags: c++, memory, stl, iterator, deque

My code occasionally crashes because of the following

```
//queue is a std::shared_ptr<std::deque<Something> >
//I can guarantee that queue will never be empty.
std::deque<Something>::iterator it = queue->end();
it--;
queue->erase(it);
```

Not always, but sometimes. It happens mostly after I added something to the front then try to delete the back.

If I change it to

```
queue->pop_back();
```

At lease haven't seen it crashing for a long time.

But can anyone enlighten me why the former code will crash? I guess it is something related to the fact that resizing may invalidate all iterators. But what I did was `--` not `++`.

Can anyone please explain to me why?

//-----------------------

//  Update

//-----------------------

My understanding is `it` is just a pointer. There is no insertion, between getting `it` and using `it`.

The only operation is `it--`. But since `it--` is a pointer moving. We always do

```
for(it = xxx.begin(); it!=xxx.end(); ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

It works fine. Or is the following illegal?

```
for(it=xxx.end();it!=xxx.begin();--it){...}
```

What I don't understand is why a pointer moving in the valid range, will cause memory corruption.

Because after `--`, `it` points the exact element I want, there is no way to re-get this pointer unless I just use `( xxx.end()-1 )` instead.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using std::deque::iterator (in C++ STL) for searching and deleting certain elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490219/using-stddequeiterator-in-c-stl-for-searching-and-deleting-certain-eleme)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: it doesn't seem to be the same problem, unless he's also using `it` after the `erase`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I assumed there was more code that did reuse it, since the 3 lines given are legitimate as long as the comment about queue being non-empty is true.

Comment: @Chris Morgan. What I did is just to erase the item. there is no further use of it. And the program crashes here, not in the code later.

Comment: @zijianz what happens if you enforce the non-empty invariant in code (instead of just in a comment). I'd assume it will complain that the queue is actually empty. If it isn't empty (enforced by code) and this is single-threaded, I can't figure out why the 3 lines of code would be a problem.

Comment: A deque iterator is not "just a pointer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your queue is not empty - everything is fine with your code.

Your statement about reverse iterating

```
for(it=xxx.end();it!=xxx.begin();--it){...}
```

can be illegal in case if you will manipulate iterator in loop body. Dereferencing xxx.end () can lead to segmentation fault.
In this case it's better to use reverse iterators:

```
for(it=xxx.rbegin();it!=xxx.rend();++it){...}
```